# Dynamic select list (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, sql

Does anyone know how I could get the select options in the following to be populated from a SQL DB?:

```
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var sel = document.createElement('select');
        sel.name = 'selRow' + rowCount;
        sel.options[0] = new Option('text zero', 'value0');
        sel.options[1] = new Option('text one', 'value1');
        cell2.appendChild(sel);
```

Thanks,
B.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't directly connect to a database, you're going to need some server-side (PHP, ASP, Coldfusion, etc.) code to do that.

**UPDATE:**
 1. In PHP create a page that reads the database & outputs XML or JSON or even the HTML code itself
 2. In Javascript make an AJAX call to that PHP page
 3. Use Javascript parse the XML/JSON/HTML response to update the page.

Using a library like JQuery will make this much easier to code. Let's assume your generating the HTML code in PHP & using JQuery, you could make & parse the AJAX call like this:

```
$.get("YourPHPPage.php", function(data){
   $('.DynamicSelect').html(data);
});
```

That will make an ajax call to the PHP page, and insert the result into your select box.

Comment: i know, but am willing to incorporate PHP

Answer (score 0):

Either take the long and inelegant route of outputting each of the `sel.options[x]` lines when the page is generated, or if you want to do it based on other information on the form, using AJAX is the way.

Comment: how would you do it the inelegant way :-)

Comment: When generating the page at the server end, have a loop which will go through all of the results and output another option to the page.

The loop would need to output sel.options[index] = new Option('text','value'); into the javascript